# Google PHP Client Library - 'Login Required' exception

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am getting the following error when attempting to access my Google Analytics data: `exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET ...my query...': (401) login required`

I'm not sure how to fix this, and I've already spent hours trying to set this up with no success.

Here's my code:

```
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("My App");
        $client->setDeveloperKey('my API key');

        $analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);

        $OBJresult = $analytics->data_ga->get(
            'ga:myprofileid' .,
            '2012-01-01',
            date("Y-m-d"),
            'ga:visits',
            array(
                'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/home',
                'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
                'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
                'sort' => '-ga:pageviews'
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only accessing your own data then you should go with a service account.  If you want to be able to login and see other peoples data then you should use Oauth2.

**service account Example:**

```
<?php
   require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.       web root.

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
    $client_id = '[Your client id]';
    $Email_address = '[YOur Service account email address Address]';     
    $key_file_location = '[Locatkon of key file]';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

    // seproate additional scopes with a comma   
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address,         
                             array($scopes),        
                             $key);     

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
         $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);      
    }       

    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);



    //Adding Dimensions
    $params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
    // requesting the data  
    $data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:89798036", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-14", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );     
?>

<html>   
Results for date:  2014-12-14<br>
    <table border="1">   
        <tr>     
        <?php    
        //Printing column headers
        foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){
             print "<td><b>".$header['name']."</b></td>";       
            }       
        ?>      
        </tr>       
        <?php       
        //printing each row.
        foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {        
            print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";   
        }    
?>      
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>     
</table>     
</html>
```

Helpful Links:

1. Code ripped from [Service account tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)
2. [Google Analytics oauth2 tutorial](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/)
3. Google's new official tutorial [Hello Analytics php](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php)

Comment: I don't want to have to login to access my data

Comment: Go with a service account then http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/  I updated the code for a service account

Answer (score 0):

The code shown does not authenticate anywhere.

I am not an expert on this API, but according to [this link](http://enarion.net/programming/php/google-client-api/google-client-api-php/) you are missing some of the following options.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('My Application name');
$client->setClientId('INSERT HERE');
$client->setClientSecret('INSERT HERE');
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
$client->setDeveloperKey('INSERT HERE'); // API key
```

Comment: I just tried that, and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Also, I don't want to login to authenticate. I simply want to be able to access my pageviews from my code. Is there a way to parse your login information or something to GA?

Comment: It is personal information, I do not think you will be able to access this via any other method, if you could, it would open everyones google data up to the masses.

Comment: Isn't there some sort of token you can send them to authenticate it? I have users on my website, and I want them to be able to see the pageviews for their products. For them to login to access some simple data would be a terrible user experience. I'm sure there's a way around this

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for my service account. What worked instead:

1. Create a service account at [IAM & Admin panel](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/). Make sure to get the key file in JSON format.
2. Download that key file to a location reachable from your script (but not reachable from the Web!)
3. Run the following code:

`$service_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile($key_file_location); // path to your json key file
    $client->addScope($service_url); // URL to the service you're planning to use
    // Run your queries here`

Answer (score 0):

[DalmTo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31262138/65387) did the trick for me, but if you don't want to hardcode `$client_id` and such you can simplify it a bit:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->client = new Google_Client();
    $credentials = $this->client->loadServiceAccountJson(__DIR__.'/../../google-service-account.json', [Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR]);
    $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

    if($this->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $this->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($credentials);
    }
}

/**
 * @return \Google_Auth_OAuth2
 */
public function getAuth() {
    return $this->client->getAuth();
}
```

Where `google-service-account.json` is the key file they give you when you create your service account. It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```